# How could Olaf survive without his flurry in Frozen II?

Tags: frozen-2

In the first movie Frozen, Elsa gives him a small flurry cloud to hover over his body and keep him completely cool, finally allowing the snowman to live his dream of experiencing summer.

[image]

However, during Frozen II, which was taking place in autumn and not winter, I don't see any cloud above him.

Where is his cloud and why hasn't he melted? It was sunny the whole film.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When he is first seen in the movie it's mentioned that he has "new permafrost" which is presumably responsible:

Comment: According to the trivia section for this film on IMDB, "There was originally a song in this film, sung by Olaf, called 'Unmeltable Me'  (https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/Unmeltable_Me) which explains how Elsa's magic has gotten more powerful, enabling her to make him unmeltable without the cloud. In the finished film, however, the only hint we get of this is Anna's line 'enjoying the new permafrost?'"